# iteration of for loop in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a simple script that uses a for loop where I want to take the value of a variable and assign it to another command and kill the screen.
 The script goes as

```
#!/usr/bin/sh/
echo 'I am going to kill the screens now';
for j in $(seq 1 1 10)
do
    i=$(grep -oP '.*?(?=\.)');
    echo $i
    screen -S $i -p 0 -X quit 
done <file1.txt
echo 'exiting...'
```

file1.txt

```
There are screens on:

    4974.eth2   (Detached)
    5105.eth11  (Detached)
    4990.eth3   (Detached)
    5006.eth5   (Detached)
    5054.eth8   (Detached)
    5070.eth9   (Detached)
    5038.eth7   (Detached)
    5022.eth6   (Detached)
8 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

So here, I am iterating through 10 lines and assigning the value of i=whatever before a period(.). eg. `4974`. Then placing `4974` in screen command and killing it. The problem here is, it is reading and grepping all the lines at a time and in the value of `i` it places as  `4974 5105 4990 5006 5054 5070 5038 5022` in the screen command and it obviously it cannot find a screen id like that and doesn't kill any screen.
How do i iterate the loop such that at a time it takes one id ie.value of `i=4974` and place only that in the screen command so that it will kill it..
Let me know if you understand my question correctly.

Comment: `for i in $(grep -oP ...); do`

Comment: also, don't use `seq` -- it's not a standard command, not part of bash, and there's no guarantee it'll be available on any given operating system. `for ((j=1; j<=10; j++))` is the equivalent that works anywhere bash is installed.

Comment: You don't use `$j` anywhere, and you already get the effect of looping by iterating over the results from `grep` -- why do you have it at all?

Comment: Also consider `read -r -a ids < <(grep -oP ...); for pid in "${ids[@]}"; do ...; done` -- that way you get the list of IDs stored in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating over a counter, iterate over your results directly:

```
set -f # disable globbing, so globs in grep's output aren't expanded
echo 'I am going to kill the screens now' >&2
for i in $(grep -oP '.*?(?=\.)'); do
    echo "$i"
    screen -S "$i" -p 0 -X quit 
done <file1.txt
echo 'exiting...' >&2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -F'[. ]+' '/Detached/ {print $2}' file.txt | while read i
do
    echo "$i"
    screen -S "$i" -p 0 -X quit 
done
```

Comment: Needs more quotes -- `echo "$i"`, `-S "$i"`

Comment: ...and using `read -r` absent a compelling reason to do otherwise is best practice.

Comment: When you know that the input data is in a strict format like this, you don't need precautions like that. That's mainly necessary when dealing with free-form input from users.

Comment: charles and Barmar..Thanks for the answers.I tried the first one which Charles had mentioned. for i in $(grep -oP '.*?(?=\.)') and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Barmar, screen socket names can be user-specified, so precautions are still called for.